# Is !$festive the same as $festive==FALSE?

Tags: php, boolean, logical-operators

I have a doubt with a few lines of PHP.

I have the following code:

```
// returns TRUE if a day is festive, FALSE otherwise
$festive = isFestive();
// 
$workingDay = $d>0 && !$festive;
```

Is `$workingDay = $d>0 && !$festive` the same as writing `$workingDay = $d>0 && $festive==FALSE;` ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No it's not, but in a way it is. !$festive, is "not festive", so it will also match things like undefined or null, as that would be "not" aswell, while checking for "false" will only match if it is 'exactly' false;

Comment: Actually, yes it is, you're thinking about "===" which will not match "false" unless $festive is EXACTLY false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.
It is different if you instead do: `$festive === FALSE` since in that case, values of `$festive` that are "falsy" will not return true, since they not exactly FALSE.

Comment: Glad to help. It is also considered a good practice to accept the answer as correct if you consider that it covers your question.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I vote for your answer, even if any other answer here (included comments) also was great.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about data types and how PHP will treat different values of non-boolean types as "false". Check out the follow snippet to illustrate this:

```
<?php
$test = false;
$test2 = null;
$test3 = 0;
$test4 = '';
$test5 = array();

var_dump($test == false);
var_dump($test2 == false);
var_dump($test3 == false);
var_dump($test4 == false);
var_dump($test5 == false);

var_dump($test === false);
var_dump($test2 === false);
var_dump($test3 === false);
var_dump($test4 === false);
var_dump($test5 === false);
```

And the resulting output (formatted):

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)

bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any `if()` expression is evaluated to be either `false` or `true`. If expression is not explicitly Boolean, then it is converted to boolean and then evaluated. [Here is how PHP converts certain types to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). In general, if value (numeric, non-boolean) is **non zero**, it is considered `TRUE`. [See this document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php) to find out more on how PHP evaluates expressions.

So in your case `$d>0` evaluates to boolean depending on `$d` real value, while for `!$festive` the `$festive` is first converted to boolean and then negated (`!`, i.e. if `$festive` is numberic value `2`, then it is converted to `TRUE` (non-zero) and then negated so the `!$festive` expression evaluates to `FALSE`.

Additional note: since your logical condition is `AND` (`&&`), if `$d>0` is evaluated to `false` the `!$festive` will not be evaluated as due to Boole's algebra `false && <anything>` is **always** `false`.